# how we can get the arraylist(both string and integer) from the resources xml

Tags: android

Hi want to get the arraylist from the resources.xml is there any code for this.please give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 87):

Use [Arrays.asList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) :

```
String[] myResArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
List<String> myResArrayList = Arrays.asList(myResArray);
```

This list will be immutable, so if you want a mutable list, just do :

```
List<String> myResMutableList = new ArrayList<String>(myResArrayList);
```

Comment: I am asking Integer arrayliat also

Comment: Same thing, use Arrays.asList and getIntegerArray.

Comment: how do you change this to an arraylist, if I wanted

Comment: I don't completely understand your comment, but I tried to edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @Pinki : could you mark this question as answered if my answer satisfied you ?

Answer (score 39):

I have done this way:

**string.xml:**

Define **String Array**:

```
 <string-array name="my_string_array">
        <item>Test 1</item>
        <item>Test 2</item>
        <item>Test 3</item>
        <item>Test 4</item>
        <item>Test 5</item>
        <item>Test 6</item>

    </string-array>
```

In **Activity.class** / **Fragment.class**:

```
List<String> myArrayList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array));
```

**Done**

Comment: @Lakshmi Narayanan,  can you please post the error ?

Comment: The error was due to context, as I tried calling it from a non activity class. Fixed it by directly calling Resources.

Answer (score 9):

A modification to Klaus' answer, to get an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
ArrayList<String> myResArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
Resources res = getResources();
Collections.addAll(myResArrayList, res.getStringArray(R.array.myResArray));
```

Answer (score 7):

Not entirely sure what you want, but this might be worth a read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

How to retrieve the array in your application with code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Comment: i am asking array list not array

Comment: There's no way to put ArrayLists in xml?

Comment: **+1** : Yes, we can't use `ArrayList` with `string-resources`. @Klaus

Answer (score 3):

```
Price_array in strings.xml is assigned to Arraylist

private ArrayList<String> price_unit;

price_unit= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Price_array)));
```